# Chef Server 12 installing Chef Client 11

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef

I have a master machine I just upgraded from Chef 11 to Chef 12, but when I go to create a new EC2 node it want to install client 11.18 instead of 12.01 or 12.03. I'm not sure if that's causing the client to bomb or not (hits a 403 trying to create the client node on master) but it can't be helping.

Does anyone know where I can tell master what version of client to install?

Comment: The term *master* does not exist in the Chef world. Are you talking about the *Chef Server* or your *Workstation*? The version of *chef-client* (on all your nodes) and the server version can be mixed between 11 and 12. Thus the 403 seems to be a different issue. Please add your logs.

Comment: Chef Server. Sorry, the guy who set this up left and I'm still trying to figure all this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the version of chef client to install through the the `--bootstrap-version` option of `knife ec2 server create`. It is your workstation that specifies, which version to install during bootstrap.

The version running on your chef server does not matter.